# Angular passing object as value in ng-repeat (instead ng-options)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I got curious problem: I'd like to pass option `ng-value` as an reference to object so `ng-model="vm.selectedItem"` will keep whole current option. I noticed that `ng-options` creates value like: `value:object:309`. In `ng-options` directive this behavior works, but unfortunately I cannot use it with `group by`. It just didn't work in my case :-/

```
vm.items = {
    label: 'Group 1',
    items: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Item 1'
    },
    {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Item 2'
    }]
}

<select ng-model="vm.selectedItem" ng-change="vm.getSomeData">
    <optgroup ng-repeat="group in vm.items" label="{{group.label}}">
        <option ng-value="?????" ng-repeat="item in group.items track by item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

Comment: So, you want the item to be the value of your option, right? So you want `ng-value="item"`. What's the problem when doing that?

Comment: @JBNizet unfortunately it's is '[Object object]' :-/

Comment: That looks to be a bug in your version. It works fine in the latest version of angular: http://plnkr.co/edit/imKRItvZb7E1kHGS0J9u?p=preview

Comment: I'm sure that I got `value="[object Object]"` when I use `<option ng-value="item">`. 
The Angular version is: 1.5.8 and I've swapped in @JBNizet Plunker framework versions. It's an Angular bug :-/ Any Idea how to solve this without updating Angular?

Comment: @cachaito
I was having the same problem, and I found that using the following:

    `<option value="{{item}}" ...`

At least returns a stringified version of the object that you are looking for.